# Reusing react components publicly available

Tags: reactjs

I have been doing react for awhile. I don't use module loaders though like webpack.

I only use npm to get the files from npm install and then get the dist from from the dist folder within. And for babel to get from es6 to es5.

I have never been able to figure out how to reuse a react component, they seem to use some kind of `require`. Can you please outline to me how I can reuse components I find on npm?

Here is example how I use it:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css" />

    <script src="/scripts/3rd/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/3rd/comm/webext.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/3rd/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/3rd/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/3rd/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/3rd/react-redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Then my js is:

```
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(ReactRedux.Provider, { store },
                React.createElement(App)
            ),
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
```

Comment: I suggest doing an intro to Node tutorial, it'll get you up to speed on JavaScript modules. Also i would suggest using the official React starter project which requires no setup and it uses modules https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: @azium I can't use create-react-app as I my target is a extension for browsers.

Comment: @netchkin Thanks for asking. I was trying to  use react-cartographer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cartographer

Comment: @netchkin I also added above how I use it without webpack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just download their code from github, there run `npm run compile` and include the content of the lib folder in your page.

However, why not use webpack? I understand that you want to build some kind of an extension to the frontend app, but with webpack, you can actually build all your code, then compile it into a simple html and css, which is usable from every browser. See this guide for more details... https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/

Comment: Thanks very much netchkin! I will try this and get back to you. I don't use webpack because the browser extension systems have their own module loading systems, which I rely on. There is connection established between the frontend and the browser. I don't understand the intricacies of what webpack does underneath, it makes me feel out of control. :(

Comment: I have often felt the same way with webpack, out of control. Fortunately, it's just a matter of playing around with it and having good tutorials. The best way to learn it is to start  simple and gradually build up. That way you'll always understand what's going on and won't put in features to u have not learnt yet.

Comment: I'll start experimenting it with it netchkin thanks for sharing that you felt the same! :)